# Why doesn't my insert query work?

Tags: wpdb

I'm trying to insert to the table in my wordpress database but for some reason it's failing all the time.

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_list_press";

$res = $wpdb->replace( $table_name, array(
    'pr_id'    => $da, 
    'pr_title' => $t,
    'pr_link'  => $str,
    'pr_date'  => $date,
    'pr_text'  => $tx,
    'pr_desc'  => $desc,
    'pr_image' => $im,
    'pr_pdf'   => $pd,
),
array(
    '%d',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
    '%s',
));

if ( $res ) {
    print( "Success" );

} else {
    print( "Failed" );
}
```

Comment: Try printing `$wpdb->last_error` to know if you get any error.

Comment: What is your `$wpdb->prefix` value ? If it's the default `wp_` then you may start removing this prefix from `"wp_list_press"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following for the table name: `$wpdb->prefix . "wp_list_press"`

Check your actual prefix and table name.  In a WP installation using "wp_" as the prefix, the above would result in "wp_wp_list_press".  Is that the table name in the db or is it just "wp_list_press"?

If the table in the db is "wp_list_press" then the above should be `$wpdb->prefix . "list_press";`

Not sure if this is contributing to the issue or not, but your data array has fewer elements than your format array.